# Send a weekly mail to inform about a library?

Tags: email, alert, task-list, notifications, workflow-tasks-list

I want to send a weekly mail and inform about a library (Tasks!). 
It would be awesome if every person who has an active task assigned to receives this mail and maybe the tasks are even listed in the mail.

The 'alert me' is not a good option, because it just sends an email if something changes, but I want a weekly summary even if nothing changes.

Is there a default way to do this from sharepoint? Or should I create a workflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an site workflow that would iterate through list create alerts and send them.